# Я сделал змейку но у меня в Jar файле не работает внутриигровой цикл

Tags: java, swing

Я попробовал сделать змейку на java (я новичок). Код весь написал, звук работает, управление и отрисовка тоже. Но когда попробовал из проекта сделать Jar файл, у  меня сам Jar файл вышло сделать но в нем не раюотал таймер, тоесть, практически ничего не работало.
Вот как выглядит структура проекта
[image: структура проекта]

Вот как выглядит игра в Intellij Idea:
[image: как должна примерно выглядеть игра]

И вот как игра выглядит в виде .jar (или .exe) файле:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код всех файлов:

Apple.java:

```
import Snake.Main;

public class Apple {
    public int posX;
    public int posY;

    public Apple(int startX, int startY) {
        posX = startX;
        posY = startY;

    }

    public void setRandomPosition() {
        posX = (int) (Math.random() * Main.WIDTH);
        posY = (int) (Math.random() * Main.WIDTH);
    }
}
```

Snake.java:

```
package Snake.lib;

import Snake.Main;

import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import java.io.IOException;

import static Snake.Main.gameOver;

public class Snake {
    public int direction = 0;
    public int length = 3;
    public int[][] Snake_ = new int[Main.WIDTH * Main.HEIGHT][2];

    public Snake(int x, int y) {
        Snake_[0][0] = x;
        Snake_[0][1] = y;
    }

    public void move() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, LineUnavailableException, IOException {

        for (int d = length; d > 0; d--) {
            Snake_[d][0] = Snake_[d - 1][0];
            Snake_[d][1] = Snake_[d - 1][1];
        }

        if (direction == 0) Snake_[0][0]++;
        if (direction == 1) Snake_[0][1]++;
        if (direction == 2) Snake_[0][0]--;
        if (direction == 3) Snake_[0][1]--;

        if (Snake_[0][0] == Main.WIDTH) gameOver();
        if (Snake_[0][0] < 0) gameOver();
        if (Snake_[0][1] == Main.HEIGHT) gameOver();
        if (Snake_[0][1] < 0) gameOver();


    }
}
```

Main.java:

```
package Snake;

import Snake.lib.Apple;
import Snake.lib.Snake;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    public static final int SCALE = 32;
    public static final int WIDTH = 20;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 20;
    public static final int SPEED = 4;
    public static boolean gameOverBoolean = false;

    Apple a = new Apple((int) (Math.random() * WIDTH), (int) (Math.random() * HEIGHT));
    public static Snake s = new Snake(10, 10);
    Timer t = new Timer(1000 / SPEED, this);

    public Main() {
        t.start();
        addKeyListener(new Keyboard());
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(color(5, 50, 10));
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE);
        g.setColor(Color.white);

        for (int xx = 0; xx <= WIDTH * SCALE; xx += SCALE) {
            g.drawLine(xx, 0, xx, HEIGHT * SCALE);
        }

        for (int yy = 0; yy <= HEIGHT * SCALE; yy += SCALE) {
            g.drawLine(0, yy, WIDTH * SCALE, yy);
        }

        for (int d = 0; d < s.length; d++) {
            g.setColor(color(0, 0, 255));
            g.fillRect(s.Snake_[d][0] * SCALE + 1, s.Snake_[d][1] * SCALE + 1, SCALE - 1, SCALE - 1);
        }

        g.setColor(color(255, 0, 0));
        g.fillRect(a.posX * SCALE + 1, a.posY * SCALE + 1, SCALE - 1, SCALE - 1);
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 28));
        g.drawString("Your score: " + (s.length - 3), 5, 40);
        if (gameOverBoolean) {
            g.setColor(Color.decode("#DC143C"));
            g.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 50));
            g.drawString("Game over!" , 50, 300);
        }
    }
    public static void gameOver() throws UnsupportedAudioFileException, IOException, LineUnavailableException {
        File gameOver = new File("audio/gameover.wav");
        AudioInputStream audioStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(gameOver);

        Clip clipGameOver = AudioSystem.getClip();
        clipGameOver.open(audioStream);
        clipGameOver.start();
        clipGameOver.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
        gameOverBoolean = true;
    }

    public Color color(int red, int green, int blue) {
        return new Color(red, green, blue);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setResizable(false);
        f.setSize(WIDTH * SCALE + 19, HEIGHT * SCALE + 48);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.add(new Main());
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (!gameOverBoolean) {
            File appleGet = new File("audio/apple_get.wav");
            AudioInputStream audioStreamGetApple;
            try {
                audioStreamGetApple = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(appleGet);
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }

            Clip clipGetApple;
            try {
                clipGetApple = AudioSystem.getClip();
            } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
            try {
                clipGetApple.open(audioStreamGetApple);
            } catch (LineUnavailableException | IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
            try {
                s.move();
            } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException | IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }

            if ((s.Snake_[0][0] == a.posX) & (s.Snake_[0][1] == a.posY)) {
                a.setRandomPosition();
                s.length++;
                clipGetApple.start();
                clipGetApple.setMicrosecondPosition(0);
            }

            for (int k = 1; k < s.length; k++) {
                if ((s.Snake_[k][0] == a.posX) & (s.Snake_[k][1] == a.posY)) {
                    a.setRandomPosition();
                }
            }

            repaint();
        }
    }

    private static class Keyboard extends KeyAdapter {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent kEve) {
            int key = kEve.getKeyCode();

            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) & s.direction != 2) s.direction = 0;
            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) & s.direction != 3) s.direction = 1;
            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) & s.direction != 0) s.direction = 2;
            if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) & s.direction != 1) s.direction = 3;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот архив со всеми файлами:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PpBQYVGDDOO5iwGVSnAFTynwy7kQrnnw/view?usp=sharing

P.S.

Исравлено.
Jar файл выглядит вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]